# React-pdf repeating same page without formatting when you scroll down

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I'm putting together a personal site that I'm trying to put my resume on. I've been partly successful with react-pdf, but it repeats the page I'm viewing at the bottom (screenshots included).

[Top of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M3fr.png)
[bottom of first page - where it start repeating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkJ36.png)

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack5';
import './Resume.css';

const Resume = () => {

  const [numPage, setNumPage] = useState(null)
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1)

  const onDocumentLoadSuccess =({numPage}) => {
    setNumPage(numPage);
    setPageNumber(1);
  }

  const changePage = (offset) => {
    setPageNumber(prevPageNumber => prevPageNumber + offset)
  }

  const changePageBack = () => changePage(-1);
  

  const changePageNext =() => changePage(+1);

  return (

 <div className='resumeContainer'>

        <Document file='./resume.pdf' onDocumentLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
          <Page 
            pageNumber={pageNumber}
            height='950'
          ></Page>
        </Document>
        <p>
          Page {pageNumber} of {numPage}
        </p>
        {pageNumber > 1 && <button onClick={changePageBack}> Previous Page</button>}
        {pageNumber < numPage && <button onClick={changePageNext}>Next Page</button>}

       </div>
       
  )
}

export default Resume
```

I've been googling and reading into the react-pdf docs but haven't found any related answers.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way easier option after spending some time away from my laptop:

embedding the link from google drive. file -> share -> publish to the web

I'm kind of a paranoid guy so I wanted to use a burner email instead of publishing my actual email - "Hide my email" came in handy in creating a burner email that would still forward to me (icloud settings on a mac).